# Question about equations

Tags: arithmetic

This is basic, I know, but it's been a long time since I've done equations. I'm watching a tutorial video on circuits.

Let's say I have this equation:

[image]

He then says "well we know all these V's are the same so we can divide both sides of that equation by V and we get 1 over R

[image]

Why does it become 1? I remember this kind of thing generally but not the specifics. What is this particular topic called so I can look it up and refresh on the subject?

Comment: You can check for any non-zero number, say $x$, that $\frac{x}{x}=1$. There is probably some reason in the video why $V$ is non-zero. I would recommend reviewing algebraic equations.

Comment: $\frac{V}{V} = \frac{1}{1}$ and $\frac{V}{V\cdot R} = \frac{1}{1\cdot R} = \frac{1}{R}$ I would review multiplying and dividing fractions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given$$\frac{V}{R_T}=\frac{V}{R_1}+\frac{V}{R_2}$$
$$V\left(\frac{1}{R_T}\right)=V\left(\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2}\right)$$
Now cancel $V$ on both sides and we get $$\frac{1}{R_T}=\frac{1}{R_1}+\frac{1}{R_2}$$

Answer (score 1):

Provided that $V\ne0$, we have:
$$V=V$$
$$\to V=1\cdot V$$
$$\to \frac VV=\frac{1\cdot V}{V}$$
$$\to\frac VV=1$$

Hence your series of equations:
$$\frac{V}{R_T}=\frac{V}{R_1}+\frac{V}{R_2}$$
becomes
$$\frac{V}{V\cdot R_T}=\frac{V}{V\cdot R_1}+\frac{V}{V\cdot R_2}$$
$$\to\frac {1}{R_T}=\frac {1}{R_1}+\frac {1}{R_2}$$